# Transactions missing from the transaction table

Tags: netsuite-rest-api

The SO has the following transactions in the related records
[image]

When attempting to get the data via a REST Query, we get no results for INV3353 and INV3421

{"q": "select id, tranid from transaction where tranid in ('INV3421', 'INV3353')"}

{"q": "select id, tranid from transaction where id in (40898, 41434)"} // INV3353 and INV3421

Any thoughts on why that would be the case?